# How to install a tar.bz2-Blender-file manually for Linux?

Tags: command-line, installation

Because I have a fatal problem with face selection in Blender and tried to install different Blender versions on different Linux versions without success, I was told to try to download Blender directly from [builder.blender.org](https://builder.blender.org/download/). Yet I only know how to install new packages using the apt-get command in the command line. In this case I have to be able to install it in another method that demands more expertise, this time it is a file that ends in .tar.bz2 that I should to install manually. Well I do not know anything, neither how to unzip, nor untar it, neither how to check for dependencies. Could you give me a quick step by step guide or any kind of suggestion.

(I am sorry, i am not quiet sure, if I should post this question here or on the Linux forum.)
I

Comment: You don't mention what flavor of linux you are using, on linux mint you'd right click on the icon and select "extract here"  to uncompress the file. Then you don't really need to "install"  blender, just run the excutable file (called *blender*)

Comment: to unpack the file using the terminal:  $ bzip2 -d filename.bz2 ,then $ tar -xvf file.tar.gz. You should then have a new folder containing all of blender files, enter that folder and type ./blender